# lucene filter: FieldCacheTermsFilter doesnot support space and special characters

Tags: search, lucene

I am using FieldCacheTermsFilter to filter out the results matching the field value as below.
Filter filter = new FieldCacheTermsFilter("city","toronto");

This works perfectly fine, whereas it doesn't work if the value has a space or special character in between like below.

Filter filter = new FieldCacheTermsFilter("city","new york");
Filter filter = new FieldCacheTermsFilter("type","b&b");

Is there way I can achieve this with any other filter.

PS: I am using FieldCacheTermsFilter for the reason that i want to search exactly on the word matching just "toronto" and not "greater toronto". I tried using TermFilter which extracts all the records containing toronto.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the `TermsFilter`, it's your analyzer.  Analysis should suit your needs for the field.

If you need to get exact matches on a whole field, you should index it as a [`StringField`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html) (or use [`KeywordAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/KeywordAnalyzer.html), or [set the field as untokenized](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldType.html#setTokenized(boolean))).  If you index with `StandardAnalyzer`, there is simply no good way to do what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks femto! I need the standard analyser for the search but I also do faceting on my search. So i need this exact search only when i drilldown on my selected faceted result. Otherwise the general search should follow standard analzying

Comment: So index it both ways, in different fields.

Comment: That should work but increases my disk space. If there is no other option I should go with this approach. Thanks a lot for your help. :)